# Extreme points of a convex set

Tags: convex-analysis

How do i find all extreme points of the set: 
$\displaystyle C=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n | \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| \leq 1 \}$?

I guess that $x=0$ is an extreme point, but how can i show it and is it the only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundary of your set is the set $$\partial C =\{x\in \mathbb R^n: \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|=1 \}$$ Thus all unity vectors $e_j$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,n$ of the form $$(e_j)_i^\pm=\begin{cases} \pm1, & \text{if } j=i \\ \phantom{\pm}0, & \text{if }j\neq i \end{cases} $$ or simply $$e_j^+=(0,0,\ldots,0,\underbrace{+1}_{j-\text{th position}},0,\ldots,0,0)$$ and $$e_j^-=(0,0,\ldots,0,\underbrace{-1}_{j-\text{th position}},0,\ldots,0,0)$$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,n$ are extreme points. They do not lie in any open line segment joining two points of $C$. Moreover, the point $x=0$ is not an extreme point since $$0=e_j-e_j$$ for any $j$ (in words: $x=0$ lies on the line segment between the points $e_j$ and $-e_j$ that are in $C$). Finally there are no other extreme points in C, since any point in $C$ can be written as a convex combination of the points $e_j, 1\le j \le n$ so the set of extremal points of $C$ is $$\mathrm{extr}\{C\}=\{\pm e_j, j=1,2,\ldots n\}$$

Comment: thank you, so for example if the set is $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \leq 1 \}$ the extreme points are all vectors for which $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=1$. is this correct?

Comment: @PaulH No and yes :). In the case to which you refer now (with the euclidean norm $x_i^2$, the boundary is a circle, so every point that lies on it is an extreme point. In general however, extreme points are the points on the boundary that do not lie on a line segment (as in the $|x_i|$ you posted above). There f.e. the point $x=(1/2, 1/2, 0, 0,...)$ fullfils $\sum |x_i|=1$ but is not an extreme point.